# Running a task on a timer

Tags: multithreading, timer, elixir, erlang-otp

I'd like to create a program that runs a function on an interval. I'm still very new to Elixir and do not know really where to start with this. My idea is that since we can use `GenServer` to create a program to sit and wait in a loop for messages, I could provide it a message (maybe `:kick`) and when it receives this message it would run the function.

However, that leaves one problem - how do I kick it without a cron job? Can I fire up a thread and run a timer that kicks it on an interval? If the main thread dies - is there an easy way to be notified and restart it?

Thank you!

Comment: http://erlang.org/doc/man/timer.html#send_interval-3

Comment: @Dogbert Wow great. How do I reference an erlang function in elixir? Could you provide a small example as an answer so I can accept it and give you points?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`timer:send_interval/2`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/timer.html#send_interval-2) with a GenServer. You'll need to call the function from the `init/1` callback and then handle the tick messages from the `handle_info` callback. Here's an example that prints 0, 1, 2, ... every second:

```
defmodule A do
  use GenServer

  def init(_) do
    :timer.send_interval(1000, :tick)
    {:ok, 0}
  end

  def handle_info(:tick, state) do
    IO.inspect state
    {:noreply, state + 1}
  end
end
```

```
iex(1)> GenServer.start_link(A, [])
{:ok, #PID<0.94.0>}
0
1
2
3
4
...
```

> If the main thread dies - is there an easy way to be notified and restart it?

You should look into [Supervisors](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Supervisor.html). The GenServer above can be added as a "worker" to a Supervisor. The Supervisor can handle restarting the GenServer if it exits for any reason.

Answer (score 1):

@Dogbert mentionned using using the `send_interval` function from Erlang, which would be used like so : `:timer.send_interval(milliseconds, process, message)`.

A quick Google search however, netted me [the `quantum-elixir` library](https://github.com/c-rack/quantum-elixir) which appears to be capable of cron like scheduling, as well as scheduling tasks at runtime.